# array_filter on object arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-filter

I have an array of objects. The objects have a `is_valid` method that has some internal logic and returns either a boolean.

Now I want to get all objects in the array that return true to `is_valid`. I can do it using a `foreach` loop.

But is there way to do it using `array_filter` in PHP without creating a new anonymous or callback function?

Comment: `array_reduce` will reduce your array to a single value you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) instead and pass your `is_valid` method to it

Comment: OP does not want a callback function @Amr Aly

Comment: @AmrAly I got confused between `array_reduce` and `array_filter`. I was basically looking for a way to filter an array of objects without creating a callback function.

Comment: so you want built-in function to retrieve your array and return only the valid ones without any callbacks

Comment: @AmrAly Yes. Basically a built-in function without any callbacks.

Comment: `array_filter` may not receive a call back however i don't know what is the behavior gonna be look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

array_filter

(PHP 4 >= 4.0.6, PHP 5, PHP 7)
array_filter — Filters elements of an array **using a callback function**

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to achive this without an anonymous callback function, as bestprogrammerintheworld said

so if you'd still like to use `array_filter`, this may be your answer:

```
array_filter($array, function($entry) { return $entry->is_valid(); } );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this one liner:

```
 Arr::filterObjects($array, 'is_valid')
```

from [this library](https://github.com/minwork/array)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$Filtered = array_filter($table, function ($item) {               
    return strpos($item->ItemCode,'PPC');
});
```

This returns an array of objects, that have `ItemCode` like PPC.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had a quicklook; strpos returns the position number of the occurrence of the string 'PPC'. This code needs to be explained, haven't looked into the logic if it even works.

Comment: Just copy some code from my project.
In this case, the function 
function ($item) { return strpos($item->ItemCode,'PPC');} will return true for the position of array members that match condition.